# Why does std::make_error_code(std::errc) exist?

Tags: c++, error-code

I understand the difference between `std::error_code` and `std::error_condition`, and I understand that `std::errc` is an "error condition" enum and not an "error code" enum.  I understand how to compare resulting `std::error_code` values against "error conditions" and so on.  I have read [Chris Kohlhoff's blog post about these types](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-5.html) several times over the years.  I have used these types and extensions to them in production code.

However, I do not understand why `std::make_error_code(std::errc)` exists.

It doesn't seem to be necessary for *comparing* actual `std::error_code` values against `std::error_condition` values: there is `std::make_error_condition(std::errc)` and conversions to `std::error_condition` and special comparison overloads for all of that.

The function's existence is especially puzzling because `std::is_error_code_enum_v<std::err>` is `false` for `std::errc`.  Presumably that is to *prevent* implicitly converting `std::errc` to `std::error_code` via `std::make_error_code(std::errc)`, but it isn't clear to me *why* preventing that is desirable when `std::make_error_code(std::errc)` exists.  In other words, if you shouldn't make an `std::error_code` out of `std::errc`, why is there a function that does just that?  And if you should, why is that implicit constructor disabled?

Is it `std::errc` a special case because code often wants to actually produce a real `std::error_code` in the `std::generic_category()` with an `std::errc` value?   In other words, is `std::errc` in some ways *both* an "error code" and an "error condition" enumeration?  (And, if so, why isn't `std::is_error_code_enum_v<std::errc>` `true`?)

Is it a special case for some other reason?

Are user-defined error conditions enums supposed to also offer `make_error_code()` like `std::errc` does, or just `make_error_condition()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::errc` has the following abilities:

1. It can be used to create an `error_condition` because it has `make_error_condition()` defined.
2. It can be used to create an `error_code` because it has `make_error_code()` defined.
3. It can participate in operations where an `error_condition` is expected because it `is_error_condition_enum`.

If the `std::errc` were implicitly convertible to the `error_code` it would use existing explicit conversion (`make_error_code`) to implement the imaginable implicit conversion. On the other hand, `make_error_code` is helpful by itself.

We can use `make_error_code` in a function that reports an `error_code` in case of error:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <system_error>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct minOrErrorResult {
    int result;
    std::error_code ec;
};

minOrErrorResult minOrError(const std::vector<int>& vec) noexcept {
    if (vec.empty())
        return { {}, make_error_code(std::errc::invalid_argument) };

    int result = *std::min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    return { result, {} };
}

int main() {
    const std::vector<int> examples[] = {
        { 3, 1, 2 },
        {},
    };
    for (auto&& vec : examples) {
        auto [result, ec] = minOrError(vec);
        if (ec)
            std::cout << "error: " << ec.message() << " [" << ec << "]\n";
        else
            std::cout << "result: " << result << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A similar example of a function that throws a `system_error` exception in case of error:

```cpp
int minOrException(const std::vector<int>& vec) {
    if (vec.empty())
        throw std::system_error(make_error_code(std::errc::invalid_argument));

    int result = *std::min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    return result;
}

int main() {
    const std::vector<int> examples[] = {
        { 3, 1, 2 },
        {},
    };
    for (auto&& vec : examples) {
        try {
            auto result = minOrException(vec);
            std::cout << "result: " << result << "\n";
        } catch (std::system_error& ex) {
            std::cout << "error: " << ex.what() << " [" << ex.code() << "]\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

If `make_error_code` is not used, we can presume that the `std::errc` constant is not interpreted as an `error_code`:

```cpp
    // Normally assume that rhs is an `error_condition`, never an `error_code`.
    //                       ↓
    if (lhs == std::errc::invalid_argument) {
        // …
    }
```

Comment: I suppose if you take my question's title to be _the_ question, then you have answered it: `make_error_code(std::errc)` exists so that you can make `error_code` from it.  But I guess the real question I have is hidden in the body of my question: Why isn't `std::is_error_code_enum_v<std::errc>` true?  Maybe the answer is simply that it makes some comparison cases of `ec == std::errc::some_error_code` ambiguous?

Comment: There should be **two enums:** `std::errcode` for codes and `std::errcond` for conditions.

As long as two enums might have identical constants, an author decided using a single `std::errc` enum for two tasks. The ambiguity came as consequence. So they decided prohibiting an implicit conversion for one of enums. From that moment, many people started thinking that `std::errc` is not an error code enum. It is!

Once again: `std::errc` is **both** an error code enum and an error condition enum, but one of its implicit conversions disabled for a technical reason.

Answer (score 0):

**`std::errc`** defines the values of portable error; a plain (factually, quite limited), set of error code values.

**`std::error_code`** is a platform-dependent error which contains an error code value and a reference to an object of the error category object.

---

From the side of program design, just there is no good reason for the implicit conversion from `std::errc` to `std::error_code`.  They logically very different set of errors:
plain vs. grouping into categories (sources)
standard set of errors vs. environment (platform and standard library implementation) dependent set of errors.

Conversions between the codes are not just changing a type or digital representation, it generally is environment-dependent logic.

A non-member function for such conversion is a quite natural solution.

---

From the side of implementation,
they are not fundamental types so that compilers would specifically support conversion from and to the types;
`std::errc`is implemented as `class enum` enumeration and cannot implement a conversion operator function as a class would;
`std::error_code` is a class, so could implement the non-explicit constructor from `std::errc`, which support the implicit conversion, as it does for `std::io_errc` and `std::future_errc` (*), but logically correspondence of the different sets of errors is just not a concern of `std::error_code`, it would violate principles of object-oriented programming (specifically, it would be inappropriate distribution of responsibility over the code entities).

---

(*) - `std::io_errc` and `std::future_errc` (as well as other `error code enumerations` having ) are  implicitly convertible to `std::error_code` because they just are the same errors as `std::error_code` store - `std::error_code` store exactly the same error code value and a reference to corresponded category of the error object; the errors sets are just subsets of the whole set which storing supported with `std::error code`.

---

The implicit conversion just would make program design worse and error-prone (specifically, illogical distribution of responsibility over the code and prone to covert and undesired conversion).

Comment: `error_code` has implicit conversions from other enum types that specialize `is_error_code_enum<T>` via the templated constructor, including `std::io_errc` and `std::future_errc`, by using a `make_error_code()` overload for each.  The above answer seems to be based on the premise that such conversions cannot be achieved and do not exist, which isn't the case, so I don't think it answers my question.  I ask (among other things) why there is a `make_error_code()` for `errc` which is then _not_ available for use by this templated implicitly-converting `error_code` constructor.

Comment: @BradSpencer, I am not sure why you call conversion with `std::make_error_code` implicit in the comment. It not what is called `implicit conversion` in C++: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion . In your question you asked why there is no constructor in `std::error_code` accepting `std::errc` (so that to convert implicitly), I answered your question.

Comment: Constructor 3 from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code/error_code is the implicit conversion from "error code enum" types (for which `is_error_code_enum` is true).  This is a one-argument non-explicit constructor converting constructor as per your link and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor .  My question is "Why does `std::make_error_code(std::errc)` exist?".  It is not "Why is there no constructor on `error_code` accepting `errc`?"

Comment: @BradSpencer, You wrote in the body of your question *“why is that implicit constructor disabled?”* This exactly would be the non-explicit constructor on `std::error_code` accepting `std::errc`. 
The function `std::make_error_code(std::errc)` exists because it can be useful. There is no implicit conversion here because it just would make program design logically worse and error-prone. [Look at the next comment...]

Comment: [...continuation:] `std::io_errc` and `std::future_errc` (as well as other `error code enumerations` having ) are  implicitly convertible to `std::error_code` because they just are the same errors as `std::error_code` store - `std::error_code` store exactly the same error code value and a reference to corresponded category of the error object; the errors sets are just subsets of the whole set which storing supported with `std::error code`. [Look at the next comment...]

Comment: [...continuation:] `std::errc` is a logically different set of errors, it is conceptually different: the set of error code values is plain, this set differs from what `std::error code` supports (even if an error is the same, the value of error code generally differ), the codes don’t depend on the environment (neither platform nor standard library implementation) - so there is no implicit conversion from it. [Look at the next comment...]

Comment: [...continuation:] I have edited my answer so that it focuses more on this point.

Comment: I know you are trying to help and thank you, but I think the problem here is that you actually don't know the answer to my question. That's okay, neither do I! The most relevant parts are "There is no good reason for implicit conversion" & "a non-member function for conversion is...natural", but that's just vague, as is the answer's final sentence. Please understand that I am not confused by the _mechanisms_ of conversion or how `error_code` works. I appreciate the effort you've put in here, but I hope someone aware of the rationale for the design choice will directly answer my question(s).

Comment: @BradSpencer, Thanks for the response. As it is stated in my answer post, the particulars of the poor design are illogical distribution of responsibility over the code and prone to covert and undesired conversion. There will not be any other real reasons provided here.